# Value is not assigning inside then statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In this js file I have defined this const Device that is the name of the mobile im using. The thing is when I call Device from another js it returns it empty. Why?

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

var Device = ''

DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().then(deviceName => {
  Device = deviceName + ' ('+DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion()+')'
});

export default Device;
```

Comment: It's because the `getDeviceName` call is asynchronous, so it will not work the way  you want it. Rather, I'd just call `DeviceInfo.getDeviceName()` from wherever you need it or turn this into a function that returns a `Promise` which resolves with the result of the `DeviceInfo.getDeviceName` call + whatever else you need to add to it.

Comment: @goto1 I prefer to have a separate js, but I still dont understand how to handle this

Comment: @Fran The problem is that the `export` happens before the async call to `getDeviceName()` finishes, so you're just exporting an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your current approach doesn't work is because `DeviceInfo.getDeviceName` is an asynchronous call that returns a `Promise` which resolves with the `deviceName`.

```js
var Device = ''

DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().then(...)

// the call above will not wait before it goes to next line
// so `Device` will stay as empty string and will be exported as such

export default Device
```

Instead, if you want to re-use this logic in multiple places, I suggest turning this into a function, like in the following example:

```js
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

function getDeviceFullName() {
  return DeviceInfo.getDeviceName()
    .then(deviceName => {
      return `${deviceName} (${DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion()})`
    })
}
export default getDeviceFullName
```

Then, somewhere else, you could call this function like in the following example:

```js
import getDeviceFullName from './getDeviceFullName'

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {deviceName: ""}

  componentDidMount() {
    getDeviceFullName()
      .then(deviceName => {
        this.setState({ deviceName })
      })
      .catch(/* handle errors appropriately */)
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.deviceName === "" 
      ? "Loading" 
      : this.state.deviceName;
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT as OP mentioned something about `Formik` integration.**

Haven't tested this, but something like the following would be my approach.

```js
class MyReactNativeForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    initialValues: { email: "johndoe@gmail.com", deviceName: "" }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getDeviceFullName()
      .then(deviceName => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            initialValues: {...prevState.initialValues, deviceName}
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(/* handle errors appropriately*/)
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.initialValues.deviceName === ""
      ? "Loading"
      : <Formik initialValues={this.state.initialValues} />
}
```

Comment: its not displaying anything :(

Comment: @Fran what are you seeing when you call `DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().then(deviceName => { console.log(deviceName) })`.

Comment: if I print it I see the value, but i dont know why its not displaying in the TextInput, maybe because the Formik form is already rendered?

Comment: @Fran I don't know what type of setup you have there, so I am afraid I won't be able to help.

Comment: @Fran I would suggest to save this (`deviceName`) in your `state` and then update the `initialValues` object with the values stored in `state`.

Comment: if I set devices: 'anything' in the this.state I see the value in the TextInput, but i dont see other way

Comment: @Fran have a look at the edit. Don't have a proper way to test it, but similar setup should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Someone else posted a great answer while I was typing mine up. My answer re-uses the value for Device because that is how the original question worked. Like the approved answer, you don't need to set it and forget it, but instead you can only return a cb/promise that always gets the most recent data.

Two things immediately stand out. Like @mhodges says, you can't reassign a value to a constant. Instead, you should use let.

Your next issue is trying to export the value returned by an asynchronous call. When you import `Device` from your js file, the export statement executes *before* you re-assign the value of `Device`.

What if you exported your async function or a callback instead?

Promise'able:

```
var Device;
export function getDeviceInfo() {
  if (Device) return Promise.resolve(Device);
  return DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().then(deviceName => {
    Device = deviceName + ' ('+DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion()+')';
    return Promise.resolve(Device);
  });
}
```

Usage might look like:

```
import { getDeviceInfo } from './utils';
getDeviceInfo().then((deviceInfo) => console.log('Got it!', deviceInfo));
```

Callback'able:

```
var Device;
export function getDeviceInfo(cb) {
  if (Device) return cb(Device);
  DeviceInfo.getDeviceName().then(deviceName => {
    Device = deviceName + ' ('+DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion()+')';
    cb(Device);
  });
}
```

Usage might look like:

```
import { getDeviceInfo } from './utils';
getDeviceInfo(function(deviceInfo) {
  console.log('Got it!', deviceInfo)
});
```